# Getting last file access time using BasicFileAttributes in Java SDK 1.8

Tags: java, android, classpath, static-linking

I have seen most of the previous questions here on Java 1.7 and getting the last file access time.

Here's also a good snippet on import library and how they get the last file access time: http://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-file-basic-attributes/

I did this:

```
BasicFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
FileTime time = attrs.lastAccessTime();
```

However, in my IntelliJ IDEA IDE it says, BasicFileAttributes could not be resolved.

So, I imported this:

```
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
```

But apparently, file cannot be resolved. I am running Java SDK 1.8 and I am trying to use this in my Android project if that makes a difference.

Not sure why file is missing in the library.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Android has it's own libraries. It covers most of what the standard JDK has, but it's still missing parts from JDK 7 and everything from JDK 8. If you are using a really old ADK version, though, you won't even have access to anything from JDK 7.

Comment: Hm even though, I download this JDK recently: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html and included it in my android project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Android doesn't support all Java 7 features so forget about Java 8. I mentioned Java 7 because `Files` was introduced in Java 7. Some features like `multi-catch`  are supported by Android(and starting with Kitkat `try-with-resources` ) but `Files` class is not. Note that Google doesn't use Oracle Java.

Comment: Is there something I can use in Android to get the time of last file access or if I sync with a device, is there a way to get last time sync with device? (last file access is a placeholder for the latter).

Comment: You have File class in android that supports some time related functionality but if you want something more then write NDK wrapper

Comment: What do you mean by write an NDK wrapper?

Comment: I mean that under the hood we are using linux so you can use stat, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html

Comment: What would be the simplest approach to using stat in android?

Comment: AS i mentioned by writing NdkWrapper around stat(), you can read some info regarding NdkWrapper here https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/ndk-android-application-porting-methodologies

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complex but thanks for your help! I appreciate it :D

Comment: Things would be much smoother if there would be no Google vs Oracle issue