# Extarct Metadata of a File (!) in android

Tags: android, file, metadata

I know theres a class to get Audio and Video (MediaMetadataRetriever)

And for images I downloaded a library that mostly take the Exif information.

The problem is that Screenshots on mobiles doesn't have even a single Exif information.

Every file got metadata of its creation date for the very least.

I've been searching for a way to do it in android and only found the BasicFileAttributes class in java which apparently doesn't exists in android.

Java solution - [Get the metadata of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824027/get-the-metadata-of-a-file)
android answer - [Getting last file access time using BasicFileAttributes in Java SDK 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898256/getting-last-file-access-time-using-basicfileattributes-in-java-sdk-1-8)

It feels so surreal that you cant get metadata of a file in android??

We must be missing something?

Comment: you are missing ExifInterface?

Comment: I dont need Exif, I need the purest level of metadata. apparently screenshots on mobile doesn't have any exif information.
That's why I need the metadata of the file. EG its creation time.

Comment: get it from the filesystem info